# Structuring Mod Rewrite Handler in GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mod-rewrite

I'm working with Google App Engine PHP environment and I've followed this docs on how to [simulate mod_rewrite on app engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite) I got this done okay but my concern is currently on the performance as everything goes into a single page (handler.php).

my `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: handler.php
```

The contents of my `handler.php`:

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$url = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', $path)));

if ($url[0] == 'items') {
    include('items.php');
    exit;  
}

if ($url[0] == 'users') {
    include('users.php');
    exit;  
}
```

So if the user enters a URL like www.mywebsite.com/user/dennis it will show the Users Page.

As you can see there are pages like `items.php` and `users.php` that is being included and I am worried about the performance. Could anyone tell me how to structure this efficiently. Thanks

Comment: What is it about the performance that you're concerned about? You can always save the routes you've calculated into memcache if you think you're going to end up with a lot of processing to do this.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I mean `items.php` and `users.php` are entire different pages each contains different set of css and js. `memcache` is used to speed up subsequent similar queries, right? It's the page load that I'm concerned about.

Comment: Okay with PHP and with this structure if `$url[0]` matches the first statement and `'items.php'` has been compiled even without `exit` the included `'users.php'` won't be compiled, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a similar thing in Java the solution was equivalent to caching the contents of users.php and items.php with the [Memcache service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/memcache/).

Comment: Thanks Martin yes I'll be using the memcache as well. I'm mostly concerned about the page load time and how things are compiled with my current structure. I also have some question on my comments above maybe you could enlighten me as well.

Comment: It is as you expect, if $url[0] == 'items' the PHP runtime will include only items.php and if $url[0] == 'users' the PHP runtime will include only users.php.  Each case loads only one file.

Comment: Okay, keep an eye on Resource Usage in the [AppEngine Dashboard](https://appengine.google.com/).